# force nuget package-update to replace modified files

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, nuget

I am using nuget as a tool to handly modules in my application.
On build the application is composed by copying the content of all nuget-packages (modules) into my main application. But if i use the pre-build event in visual studio to update my packages i dont get prompted if i want to replace modified files (which can happen sometimes).
When i do the same thing using the GUI - no problem, because i get the prompt there and can thus simply replace the modified stuff.

Is there any way to force nuget to replace everything or what would be even better: get a prompt for every file.